# API (C# - .NET - IIS8.5) not working after IIS security adjustments

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have this API code, It was working fine until we had some IIS adjustments for security reasons, like:

1. Disabling some SSL/TLS versions
2. Installing new self-signed SSL certificate
3. Disabling some Cipher suits

After that, just this API **return a 200 OK response without any body** on online server (**but also the API work fine on localhost**)
We managed to test other APIs through postman (online and localhost) and it’s work fine

**Anyone experienced this before can suggest a solution?**

C# .NET IIS 8.5 windows server 2012 r2

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web.Http;
using Raqeeb.Common;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;

namespace test.Apis
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.Use<GlobalExceptionMiddleware>();
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            ConfigureWebOAuth(app);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureWebOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/authorization/login"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new AuthorizationWebServerProvider(),
                //RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OAuthAccessTokenIssuer"].ToString()),
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            };

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                CookiePath="/path",
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            });


            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            //app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
            //get private key
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Utility.AssemblyDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicCertificate"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePassword"]);
            // ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicCertificate"].ToString()
            // Api controllers with an[Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { "http://localhost" },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider("http://localhost", cert)
                    },

                });
       }

        public void ConfigureAppOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/authorization/get-access"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new AuthorizationAppServerProvider(),
                //RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OAuthAccessTokenIssuer"].ToString())

            };


            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            //app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            //get private key
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Utility.AssemblyDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicCertificate"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePassword"]);
           app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { "http://localhost" },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider("http://localhost", cert)
                    },

                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Undo the changes, and reapply them one by one to see which one causes your problem.

Comment: I tried that already and that did not solve the problem (the adjustments was made by someone else and he is not available right now, I tried to Undo all the changes but something still missing)

Comment: 200 responses without body are often caused by bad code (illy written exception handler), and rarely caused by IIS configuration changes.

Comment: Confusingly, the application was working before the they change the configuration, also the application still working in localhost.

Comment: I also tried to do some logging and all the variables was getting there values

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.